# How to use Liferay language.properties with jsp expression language?

Tags: jsp, liferay

In Liferay, I want to do a portlet displaying a greeting with the user name.
This message could be in different language.

how can I put a parameter from jsp expression language to language property String?

I tried to write something like this in language.properties

```
portlet.body.line1=Hello ${name},
```

and use it in my view.jsp

```
<liferay-ui:message key="portlet.body.line1" />
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use expression language in this way. You'll have to know what the translated text contains and use Language.properties like this:

```
portlet.body.line1=Hello {0}
```

in a jsp like this

```
<liferay-ui:message key="portlet.body.line1" arguments="Pierre" />
```

Actually, you might be able to use EL here and use `arguments="${name}"` - try it. the arguments attribute can also take a String array in case you have more parameters (like "{0}, {1}")